# How to convert non Web-Mercator coordinates to the tile Y, X, Z coordinates?

Tags: leaflet, convert, openlayers-2, tiles, mod-tile

I just found that **leafletjs** and **openlayers** have two different conventions to convert coordinates from EPSG:4326 (WGS 84) to tile names (`{Z}/{X}/{Y}`).

Thus I would like to have more information about the origin and usages of such two standards, and I would also know if there is a generalized way to implement the conversions from any projection (using only proj4 data) to tiles names.

I added the following *preliminary* snippet to **mod_tile**, so that it can serve EPSG:4326 (WGS 84) tiles:

```js
} else if (strcmp(srs, "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs") == 0) {
    syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Using wgs84 projection settings");
    prj = (struct projectionconfig *)malloc(sizeof(struct projectionconfig));
    prj->bound_x0 = -180;
    prj->bound_x1 =  180;
    prj->bound_y0 = -90;
    prj->bound_y1 =  90;
    prj->aspect_x = 2;
    prj->aspect_y = 1;
```

To display a tiled map I use:

**Leafletjs**

```
L.tileLayer('.../base/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');`
```

**Openlayers**

```js
('.../base/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').replace('{z}', (tileCoord[0] - 1).toString())
                            .replace('{x}', tileCoord[1].toString())
                            .replace('{y}', (-tileCoord[2] - 1).toString());
```

The results with the two libraries is exactly the same, if I adapt the zoom level.

***EDIT***: My target is to provide a generalized patch for mod_tile (and ev. other services), but from the answer below, I think I need to provide extra parameters in a configuration file of mod_tile (e.g. `renderd.conf`) to generate the correct tile with the expected name.

Comment: Have you taken your openlayers code from http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/examples/xyz-esri-4326-512.html ?

Comment: I copied my code from that source.  I just forgot to set the minZoom, which removes the error on zoom 0 ({Z}: "-1").

Comment: That script is using ArcGIS tiles, which (I guess) follow a scheme similar to TMS, so you should only rely on that scheme if your maps are hosted in ArcGIS online or such. See http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Map_Tile/02r3000000pt000000/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good explanation at the [OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames). It boils down to projecting EPSG:4326 coordinates to EPSG:3857 and working the X and Y coordinates of the tile from the X and Y coordinates in that CRS.

The "generalized" way to provide tiles for any CRS is [TMS](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification).

Comment: I'm asking about tile names in **EPSG:4326**.  Leafletjs uses Google Maps style [so also OSM style] (top to bottom in {Y}, zoom zero is one tile).  Your links about TMS explain the other standard (bottom to top in {Y}).  I still need to find what service (in TMS style) uses the origin and zoom level as expected in Openlayers.

Comment: There is no suck thing as "the tile grid that OpenLayers expects" - OL3 has *superb* support for [tile URL schemes](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/apidoc/ol.source.XYZ.html), and [user-defined tile grids](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/apidoc/ol.tilegrid.TileGrid.html).

If you need to serve EPSG:4326 in a tiled fashion, I heartily recommend you set up a TMS server for them.

Comment: I mean a sort of _default_. OL3 chooses, for XYZ, a default way to construct tile urls.  My code (copied from OL3 examples) mangle urls with XYZ.tileUrlFunction so that I view the same tile in the same way as leafletjs (using the the default tile names).  So, what should be the _default_ rendering in mod_tile, on maps with EPSG:4326 projection?  The question is about what are the reasons behind the two different defaults, not how to view tiles with the other default.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to you.
In google maps API.

code is in link below.

```
  var tile = new google.maps.Point();
  var point = new google.maps.Point();
  var zoom = map.getZoom();

  var proj = map.getProjection();

  point = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);

  tile.x = Math.floor( (point.x / 256.0) * Math.pow(2, zoom));
  tile.y = Math.floor( (point.y / 256.0) * Math.pow(2, zoom));

  if (tile.x < 0 || tile.y < 0) return;
  if (tile.x >= (1 << zoom) || tile.y >= (1 << zoom)) return;

  var boundspixels = tile.x*256 + " " + tile.y*256 + " " + (tile.x+1)*256 + " " + (tile.y+1)*256;

  latLng1 = proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(tile.x*256/ Math.pow(2, zoom),(tile.y+1)*256/ Math.pow(2, zoom)));
  latLng2 = proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((tile.x+1)*256/ Math.pow(2, zoom),tile.y*256/ Math.pow(2, zoom)));
  var boundswgs84 = latLng1.lng()+" "+latLng1.lat()+"<br/>"+latLng2.lng()+" "+latLng2.lat();

  latLng = proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(((tile.x+1)*256-128) / Math.pow(2, zoom),(tile.y*256+100) / Math.pow(2, zoom)));

  initialResolution = 2 * Math.PI * 6378137 / 256;  // == 156543.0339
  originShift = 2 * Math.PI * 6378137 / 2.0; // == 20037508.34
  res = initialResolution / Math.pow(2, zoom);
  tile.y = ((1 << zoom) - tile.y - 1); // TMS
  var boundsmercator =  (tile.x*256 * res - originShift) + " " + (tile.y*256 * res - originShift) +
  "<br/>" + ((tile.x+1)*256 * res - originShift) + " " + ((tile.y+1)*256 * res - originShift);
```

[maptiler](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/)